# how to prove that the ceiling(x) = floor(x) + 1?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was just wondering if someone could please explain how one would go about proving that the ceiling(x) = floor(x) + 1 ?
I have never been very good with inequalities, and that seems to be the only way of proving this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Timothy

Comment: It's only true for $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$. For example $\lceil 0 \rceil = 0 \neq 1 = 0 + 1 = \lfloor 0 \rfloor + 1$.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Relations_among_the_functions

Comment: You can write $\lceil x \rceil$ by placing \lceil x \rceil between dollar signs.  You can write $\lfloor x \rfloor$ by placing \lfloor x \rfloor between dollar signs.

Comment: The proper equation would be
$$
\lceil x\rceil=\lfloor x\rfloor+[x\not\in\mathbb{Z}]
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you wrote is only true if $x$ is not an integer:

- The ceiling is defined as the smallest integer that is larger or equal to $x$
- The floor is defined as the largest integer that is smaller or equal to $x$.

This means that if $x\in\mathbb Z$, then $\lceil x\rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor = x$

On the other hand, if $x\notin \mathbb Z$, then it is simple to see that since $y=\lfloor x \rfloor$ is smaller or equal to $x$, then

- $y\neq x$, therefore $y<x$, meaning that $y$ cannot be $\lceil x \rceil$.
- $y+1$ must be larger than $x$, because if $y+1\leq x$, then $y\neq \lfloor x \rfloor$

Therefore, $y+1$ is the smallest integer that is larger than $x$, so $y+1=\lceil x \rceil.$